DIV que cambian al hacer clic en otro div
Estoy intentando hacer un codigo que me permita mostrar y ocultar diferentes div dependiendo del div al que haga clic. La cuestion es que el codigo me funciona bien cuando hago el primer clic pero ya no es capaz de hacer más, es como que se queda pillado y ya no hace nada.
Este es el javascript que tengo:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var divAcabado = document.getElementById("acabadoaparece");
  var divAvance = document.getElementById("granavanceaparece");
  var divTorica = document.getElementById("toricaaparece");

    document.querySelector(".acabadoclic").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Ocultar el div "acabadoaparece" y "toricaaparece"
    divAvance.style.display = "none";
    divTorica.style.display = "none";
    
    // Mostrar el div "granavanceaparece"
    divAcabado.style.display = "flex";
  });
  
  document.querySelector(".granavanceclic").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Ocultar el div "acabadoaparece" y "toricaaparece"
    divAcabado.style.display = "none";
    divTorica.style.display = "none";
    
    // Mostrar el div "granavanceaparece"
    divAvance.style.display = "flex";
  });
  
  document.querySelector(".toricaclic").addEventListener("click", function() {
    // Ocultar el div "acabadoaparece" y "granavanceaparece"
    divAcabado.style.display = "none";
    divAvance.style.display = "none";
    
    // Mostrar el div "toricaaparece"
    divTorica.style.display = "flex";
  });
});


a mi me funcionan bien los clicks, agrega tu HTML

y detalla un poco que comportamiento esperas

¿Tienes varios elementos de cada .acabadoclic, .granavanceclic y .toricaclic o son únicos?, si son varios deberías usar querySelectorAll y después iterar para añadirle un evento a cada uno, de lo contrario siempre lanzarás el evento al primero que se encuentre en el documento. Si son únicos procura mejor usar ids y getElementById
